# Long press a custom physical button on android device with appium java

Tags: java, android, appium

I have a an custom-made phone in which it has a specific SOS button that I need to long press.

I am trying to do key press like this.

```
   driver.longPressKey(new KeyEvent( AndroidKey.HOME) );
```

which is working but Custom key code 287. How do I send that? I tried something like this

```
driver.longPressKey(new KeyEvent( AndroidKey.valueOf("287")) );
```

but this gives an enum error

Version: java-client: 7.5.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Error Reason**

`AndroidKey` is Enum and `valueOf` method works like:

```
AndroidKey.valueOf("HOME");
```

while the HOME is defined in Enum.

```
public enum AndroidKey {
    UNKNOWN(0),
    ...
    HOME(3),
    ...
```

**Press Custom Key Code**

Key Code 287 is not present in *AndroidKey* Enum.

But `KeyEvent` constructor requires it.

For this case I suggest to make a custom `KeyEvent` child class.

```
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableMap
import io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.KeyEvent

import static java.util.Optional.ofNullable

class MyKeyEvent extends KeyEvent {

    private int keyCode;

    public MyKeyEvent(int keyCode) {
        this.keyCode = keyCode;
    }

    @Override
    public Map<String, Object> build() {
        final ImmutableMap.Builder<String, Object> builder = ImmutableMap.builder();
        final int keyCode = ofNullable(this.keyCode)
                .orElseThrow(() -> new IllegalStateException("The key code must be set"));
        builder.put("keycode", keyCode);
        return builder.build();
    }
}
```

and for the long press:

```
driver.longPressKey(new MyKeyEvent(287));
```

---

**Disclaimer**

As I see this might work (since the Appium command executor will get the valid structure for long-press command), but I haven't the ability to run this code on some device or emulator. And I don't know the driver behavior once it'll try to execute some unknown key code.

So, let me know if it doesn't work, and I'll try to improve/fix.

Comment: thanks so much max. can i ask you for further resources on KeyEvent child class. i don't really understand it. thanks again.

Comment: @vaibhavcool20 does this work for you? Do you need some explanation of how it works, or should this code be improved? Or do you need help in applying this code for your project?

Comment: no the code works perfectly. i just don't understand it.

Comment: `AppiumDriver` implements `io.appium.java_client.android.nativekey.PressesKey` which contains `void longPressKey(KeyEvent keyEvent)` method. So we need to instantiate some `KeyEvent` object. But `KeyEvent` class accepts only `AndroidKey` enum arguments for the keycode (which embed the real key-code int value). But eventually `KeyEvent`  extracts the key-code integer from enum and put it to appium-command in this method `public Map<String, Object> build()`.

Comment: So I've created a child class, which accepts the key-code integer directly and put it into appium command. `build()` method just returns the appium-command body map with  e.g. `"keycode": 287`.

Comment: `Map<String, Object> build()` method is mainly copypasted from the parent class and adopted. You could look at the parent method implementation, so it might become more clear.